# How to prevent pages from posting on my Facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

Some (unknown) pages are posting their content (i.e. sharing videos, articles..) on my Facebook timeline without my permission. The problem is that I am not able to see these posts on my timeline! However, my friends can see them.

Is there any way to stop this?

Please note that I changed the setting Timeline and Tagging to Only Me, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Do you have any authorised third party apps that could perhaps have this permission?

Comment: What do you mean by third party apps ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/apps